# Can a throw-in be re-taken in football (soccer)?

Tags: rules, football, officiating

During corner kicks, players sometimes commit an infringement against their opponent just before the ball is in play. Then the referee blows her whistle because she is either warned by another match official or sees the infringement herself. After that, she takes the proper disciplinary action and makes the corner kick be re-taken. Should the referee follow the same procedure if a similar event happens during a throw-in?